# x11 limit mouse movements

Tags: qt, ubuntu, x11

I try to lock mouse cursor movements to the left half of the screen. I have following screen setup:

On the left side is a Qt window of size 1120x1080, on the right side a GL window of size 800x1080.

I use Openbox window manager under Ubuntu 12.10. The window layout stays fixed.

I need to restrict mouse movement to the Qt window.

Comment: The way video games keep the mouse pointer from leaving a window is by "warping" it, that is, moving it back to the center constantly. I don't think there's a way to get X11 to clip the mouse pointer to a certain area for you, you have to move it back whenever it leaves.

Answer (score 0):

To get the mouse to stay in the window, enable mouse movement with:

```
setMouseTracking(true);
```

and override `void QWidget::mouseMovement( QMouseEvent * event )`

```
void TheWindow::mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
{
    // get window size without frame
    QRect s = geometry();

    // get current cursor position
    int x = event->globalX();
    int y = event->globalY();

    bool reset = false;

    // Check cursor position relative to window
    if (event->x() < 0) 
    {
        x -= event->x();
        reset = true;
    }
    else if (event->x() >= s.width())
    {
       x += s.width() - event->x() - 1;
       reset = true;
    }

    if (event->y() < 0)
    {
        y -= event->y();
        reset = true; 
    }
    else if (event->y() >= s.height())
    {
        y += s.height() - event->y() - 1;
        reset = true;
    }

    // if reset needed move cursor  
    if (reset) QCursor::setPos(x,y);

}
```

Comment: Note: this solution does not work when Application run via TeamViewer, Virtual Box (with mouse integration turned on), Google Remote Desktop, RDP and similar application. Implementation uses Absolute mouse coordinates that sends from Host and does not provides interface to set mouse position from the Slave for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

this involving `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()`. If you have an item which you want to restrict to a certain area then reimplement `itemChange()` for that item and monitor `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged` changes to see whether the items wants to be placed outside your area of interest and prevent that by returning a position from inside that area. for example:

```
QVariant QGraphicsItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    switch (change) {
    case ItemPositionHasChanged:
        if(x() < -200 || y() < -200 || x() > 200 || y() > 200)
            setPos(0, 0);
        graph->itemMoved();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    };

    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```